# How can I ensure that data pulled from mysql database is recognized in Mssql and SSIS?

Tags: .net, mysql, windows, sql-server-2008, ssis

How can I ensure that data pulled from mysql database  is recognized in Mssql and SSIS
I am  pulling records from Mysql database which is on Linux  box and store the records on MSSQL database. When I get the primary key from the same records to compare with records that are already on MSSQL database table.  The sql or SSIS  are failing to compare the existing records. For example
PK   Column1 ( From Linux on Mysql) Table1
QT1     Blue
QT2    Green

PK  Column1( Windows MSSQL)  Table2
QT1    Blue
QT2   Green

When I pull the same records and compare the sql is showing as if these records do not exist or not there.
The sql is as follows
Select * from table2 where PK NOT  IN (SELECT PK from table2). This is in Microsoft Server Integrating Services
But it is pulling all the records. What things should I do to ensure that it works properly? Are there any characters I should change? All the records are in the same case.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can choose this in phpmyAdmin, try to choose the option export to sql or here is the link :
[Export Data from MySql to Sql Server](http://www.waynezim.com/2010/03/how-to-export-mysql-database-to-mssql-using-phpmyadmin/)

Comment: I am using SSIS Not PHPmyadmin